# Encryption library and compression library for c/c++ in linux

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, compression

I need a library which can encrypt/decrypt files with a symmetric key in linux.

I also need a library to compress the files that are going to be encrypted. Which of these libraries should I use for compression?: gzip, zlib, libarchive, libtar.

Both the libraries has to be able to decrypt/decompress to memory, as I do not want to leave any traces on the harddrive.

This could probably be done with a password protected archive, though I do not know if there are any pros/cons to it over using both libraries.

Comment: There are lots of libraries out there that will perform both of these tasks.  30 seconds of research would probably get you quite a list.  What have you found so far?  Why wasn't it suitable?  Let us know the specifics and we can give you better answers.

Comment: The encryption libraries I have found until now are all from 2000, which I think is outdated.

After I decompress and decrypt the files, I want to be able to read them without saving anything to the harddrive.

Comment: @HorseSMith the first public release of the RSA algorithm can be dated back to the 1977, the pgp project is from the 90's, cryptography it's full of really old algorithms and libraries if you think that one from the 2000 is "old". Nevertheless the most important thing is the implementation, not how old the algorithm is.

Comment: Last release of GNU TSL library is from 2012, and it has some functions for symmetric cryptography.

Comment: Remember that you can't control the o/s swapping your program out to the hard drive at inconvenient moments, so your data may get written to hard disk despite your best efforts to keep everything in memory.  Also, since you say you've found some libraries, wouldn't it be sensible to list them so that people can advise you on whether they're reasonable and don't waste their time suggesting what you already know about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What if I mount my hdd as read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here are the concrete recommendations in form of the specific Ubuntu packages:

- `libmcrypt-dev`: can handle dozen symmetric algorithms (AES/Rijndael, Blowfish...)
- `zlib1g-dev`: gzip is a one possible choice between speed and size